# Reading from JSON column with dynamic element name

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have a table that contains json data that I need to unpick and store in a relational DB. I am using an Oracle DB 19.0 and have created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE J_PAGE
  (
    PK_PAGE_ID         NUMBER ( 10 , 0 ) 
  , FK_RESP_ID         NUMBER ( 10 , 0 ) DEFAULT -1
  , CL_PAGE_ID         NUMBER ( 10 , 0 ) DEFAULT -1
  , CL_RESP            CLOB CONSTRAINT CK_PAGE_01 CHECK ( CL_RESP IS JSON ) 
  , CL_DT              DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
  ) ;
```

The column CL_RESP is a clob value that returns the response from a call to UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE.

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "results": [
        {
            "key": "stories",
            "id": "10000"
        },
        {
            "key": "stories",
            "id": "10001"
        }
    ],
    "stories": {
        "10000": {
            "title": "story1",
            "description": null,
            "start_date": "2020-04-01",
            "id": "10001"
        },
        "10001": {
            "title": "story2",
            "description": null,
            "start_date": null,
            "id": "10001"
        }
    },
    "meta": {
        "count": 2,
        "page_count": 1,
        "page_number": 1,
        "page_size": 20
    }
}
```

I need to extract the contents of the "stories" element but I'm getting stuck where the next element doesn't have a static name.

I know I can do the following to return 1 row using story 10001...

```
SELECT
  page.CL_RESP.stories."10001".title[*] CL_TITLE
FROM
  J_PAGE page ;
```

But I need all stories so perhaps a wildcard in place of 10001?

```
SELECT
  page.CL_RESP.stories.*.title[*] CL_TITLE
FROM
  J_PAGE page ;
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

```
SELECT
  t.*
FROM 
  J_PAGE o, 
  JSON_TABLE ( o.CL_RESP , '$.stories.*'
    COLUMNS (
      CL_TITLE          VARCHAR2   PATH '$.title'
    , CL_DESC           VARCHAR2   PATH '$.description'
    , CL_START_DT       TIMESTAMP  PATH '$.start_date'
    , CL_ID             NUMBER     PATH '$.id'
    )
  ) t ;
```